# How to filter object from one key only and return it as json?

Tags: node.js, json, reactjs, express, axios

I have a back end route that fetches all the user data from and returns it as json. I would like to filter all that data to not forward the hashed password. How can I do that? My current code:

```
router.get("/", isLoggedIn, (req, res, next) => {
  User.findById(req.user._id)
    .then((user) => {
      console.log("Fetching user data, remove password", user);
      res.status(200).json(user);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({ errorMessage: err.message });
    });
})
```

;

Comment: You can just delete the keys that you don't want to send ```delete user.password```, or unpack that object to smaller subset of properties ```const {password, ...rest} = user;``` and send back rest with your response

Comment: It still sends the password ;/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `mongoose` you can use [Query.prototype.select()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select) function to filter the properties:

```
router.get("/", isLoggedIn, (req, res, next) => {
  User.findById(req.user._id).select("-password") //--> prefixing a path with - will flag that path as excluded
    .then((user) => {
      res.status(200).json(user);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({ errorMessage: err.message });
    });
})
```

Comment: It still sends the password, I've tried with ...res  but it does not change anything.

Comment: That is weir, I simplify my answer, the property that you want to remove is "password"?

Comment: yes, I am passing the object with user data to the front end but I just want to skip passing the password for extra security.

Comment: I updated my answer, if you are using mongodb you can use select

Comment: @mnn what are you using to store the data?

Comment: thanks, .select sorted the issue. Do you know why it was not filtering with ...res etc.?

Comment: Your welcome, the reason is Model.findById() returns a Query object, not the data

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1: Delete the property**

```
router.get("/", isLoggedIn, (req, res, next) => {
  User.findById(req.user._id)
    .then((user) => {
      delete user.password;
      res.status(200).json(user);      
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({ errorMessage: err.message });
    });
})
```

**Method 2: Create a new object overwriting the password property**

```
router.get("/", isLoggedIn, (req, res, next) => {
  User.findById(req.user._id)
    .then((user) => {
      user = Object.assign({}, user, {password: null});

      res.status(200).json(user);      
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({ errorMessage: err.message });
    });
})
```

**Method 3: This is a Mongoose document? You need to convert it to a standard object first**

```
let filteredUser = user.toObject();
delete filteredUser.password;
res.status(200).json(filteredUser);
```

Comment: I have tried that but it still returns with password^^

Comment: Gave you a second method

Comment: It still sends the password, I've tried with ...res as well but it does not change anything.

Comment: What does your `user` object look like?

Comment: ``Object
createdAt: "2021-02-18T14:57:23.403Z"
email: "mnblski@gmail.com"
password: "$2b$10$JPSh6.lHcW756MKl4G.H1uCY4xdsP8u0rBMX1MwHvC9OVFsBzYM6G"
profilePic: ""
updatedAt: "2021-02-18T14:57:23.403Z"
username: "Marcel600"
__v: 0
_id: "602e8053210e3318048c3aa8"
__proto__: Object``

Comment: You didn't mention your object  has a prototype.  Try `delete Object.getPrototypeOf(user).password;`

Comment: still nothing, I have provided some more code, please check below

Comment: This is a mongoose document?  Updated answer shows how to convert it to an object first.

Comment: Thanks, that worked too! I'll save both solutions for future ref

Answer (score 0):

If I run this code : `const { password, ...data } = user;` the ...data is being printed like below:

```
{
      '$__': InternalCache {
        strictMode: true,
        selected: {},
        shardval: undefined,
        saveError: undefined,
        validationError: undefined,
        adhocPaths: undefined,
        removing: undefined,
        inserting: undefined,
        saving: undefined,
        version: undefined,
        getters: {},
        _id: 602e8ecd9ffbba1c133db8ce,
        populate: undefined,
        populated: undefined,
        wasPopulated: false,
        scope: undefined,
        activePaths: StateMachine {
          paths: [Object],
          states: [Object],
          stateNames: [Array]
        },
        pathsToScopes: {},
        cachedRequired: {},
        session: undefined,
        '$setCalled': Set {},
        ownerDocument: undefined,
        fullPath: undefined,
        emitter: EventEmitter {
          _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
          _eventsCount: 0,
          _maxListeners: 0,
          [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
        },
        '$options': { skipId: true, isNew: false, willInit: true, defaults: true }
      },
      isNew: false,
      errors: undefined,
      '$locals': {},
      '$op': null,
      _doc: {
        profilePic: '',
        _id: 602e8ecd9ffbba1c133db8ce,
        username: 'mnblski5000',
        email: 'xxi@gmail.com',
        password: '$2b$10$i.sbWZuPF1dro.5OAegfie5BeyrHvH5vHWWbnWI9isRDDczkoy2eK',
        createdAt: 2021-02-18T15:59:09.899Z,
        updatedAt: 2021-02-18T15:59:09.899Z,
        __v: 0
      },
      '$init': true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
router.get("/", isLoggedIn, (req, res, next) => {
  User.findById(req.user._id)
    .then((user) => {
      const filteredUser = {...user, password: undefined};

      res.status(200).json(filteredUser);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({ errorMessage: err.message });
    });
})
```